# Entify Framework How to do Where Or using Linq (Predicate)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to do an OR. I thought you could do this with Predicate, so I tried this

```
var products = ctx.Products.Where(x => .....);

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();
foreach (Category categ in categs)
  predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Categories.Select(c => c.Id).Contains(categ.Id)
                              || p.Categories.Select(c => c.Category1.Id).Contains(categ.Id)
                              || p.Categories.Select(c => c.Category1.Category1.Id).Contains(categ.Id));
products = products.Where(predicate);
```

but it gives me this error

> System.NotSupportedException: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Could someone please help me solve this? Thanks in advanced.

A `Product` can have one or more `Category`.
`Category` may have a "parent category" called `Category1`. Those long 3 lines above is to select products under a category or its child categories.

I googled and found LinqKit, but I want to avoid adding a 3rd party just for this. But if I have to use LinqKit, is it easy to install?

Comment: What would expect the resulting SQL to look like?

Comment: Babcock, the SQL query will be too complex, but I added description that should make it clearer. Thank you

Comment: `the SQL query will be too complex` - Are you sure that there is a SQL query that supports the behavior you're expecting? I'm far from a SQL expert but the way I would approach this in SQL would be to break it up into separate queries with a `UNION`. This may be a simpler approach.

Comment: Yes I'm sure you can do that with SQL query. You're right, union seems to work, I just tried it. But I think it won't be efficient because it has to get all the products from the database everytime. I'm interested to use Predicate it looks cool :(

Comment: Are all categories (parent and child) in one table? And how do they refer to one another? BTW, you could use Any() in stead of Select().Contains().

Comment: Yes in 1 table. A column called `ParentCategoryId` is linked to the `Id` column in the same table (`Categories`). Linq created `Category1`, which is the parent category. Thanks GertArnold!

Comment: @GertArnold Btw, how do you do it with Any()?

Comment: p => p.Categories.Any(c => c.Id == categ.Id). Could you make a view with a [recursive query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) to get a list of CategoryId's with related id's at any level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works

```
if (categs.Length > 0)
{
  List<Product> tmpProducts = new List<Product>();
  foreach (Category c in categs)
  {
    var tmp = ctx.Products.ToList().Where(x => x.IsUnderCategory(c));
    tmpProducts = tmpProducts.Union(tmp).ToList();
  }
  products = products.ToList().Intersect(tmpProducts).AsQueryable();
}
```

IsUnderCategory is an extension

```
  public partial class Category
  {
    public bool IsUnderCategory(Category categ)
    {
      if (Id == categ.Id) return true; // is itself

      if (Parent == null)
        return false;

      return Parent.IsUnderCategory(categ);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the `ToList`'s are necessary?

Comment: Yes, otherwise tmpProducts would be empty until the last line, hence only the last category would be effective.

Comment: Are you serious? You fetch the whole Product table in memory for each category in `categs` and at the end yet another time.

Comment: I know. That was the reason I posted this question, to see if there is an efficient way of doing it. At the end, `products` was the filtered products, may not be all products.